# Start input field with text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a form field to start with http:// when a persons clicks or starts typing into the field. Below is the code I am attempting it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var input = $( "#website" );
  input.val( input.val() + "http://" );
</script>
```

How can I force the field to always start with http:// when a person types in that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#website").focus(function(){
        var $input = $(this);
        if ($input.val() === '') {
            $input.val('http://');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This will replace the existing contents of the field if the user clicks back in the field to edit the value so you probably want to include a check along the lines of `if $input.val() === ''...`

Answer (score 0):

Something to start with perhaps, though it'll need some tweaking:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(e){
    var s = 'http://',
        valid = this.value.substring(0, s.length) === s; 
        //check if text starts with 'http://'

    if(!valid)
        this.value = s;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L8j281gz/